# Table overlay labels

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm making a gantt chart-esqe application using a table as a grid for each of the days. When one of the days is allocated the `td` will be assigned a class which changes its colour to what resource is being used. I'm trying to put a label on top which shows which resource is allocated like the example below.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100px;
}

td {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: black solid 1px;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="green">sdfsdfsfsdfs</td>
      <td class="green"></td>
      <td class="green"></td>
      <td class="green"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="green">te</td>
      <td class="green"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="red">longstring</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="red">longstring</td>
      <td class="red"></td>
      <td class="red"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The first two rows which are green work nicely. The label overflowing showing the whole name. I have added a 4th row which does display properly. However the problem comes with the third line. The name is longer than all the days it is allocated so it overflows into the empty `td`s.

So the only line which doesn't display properly is the 3rd one. The overflow should be hidden so it only display "lon".

Is there any CSS trick which can stop overflowing into an area with a different background/class? Or maybe a javascript solution to prevent overflowing on the last `td`?

Comment: `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: @Matt.S `overflow: hidden;` doesn't work as it stops the first line from working. Unless you mean only do that on the last `td` but I may not necessarily know if it is or not

Comment: so you only want it to overflow when there are `td`s of the same color next to it?

Comment: @Matt.S yes. I'll edit the question to make that a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `z-index` on white cell and assign position `static` on colored cell to get what you want.

Live demo :

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100px;
}


td {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: black solid 1px;
}

td {
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}

.green {
  position: static;
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  position: static;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="green">sdfsdfsfsdfs</td>
      <td class="green"></td>
      <td class="green"></td>
      <td class="green"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="green">te</td>
      <td class="green"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="red">longstring</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="red">longstring</td>
      <td class="red"></td>
      <td class="red"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note : There is some trouble with border style

Comment: Shortening it to ellipsis is fine with me however that is only if it is the last `tr`. I've edited the question with another test case to clarify what I mean.

Comment: @TomDee I updated, there is some trouble with border. Say me if it's a problem